# Visualforce - Apex Parameters are not getting passed to controller

Tags: visualforce

VF Code

```
<apex:pageBlock title="New Expense" rendered="{!isNewExpense}" id="pb">
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="Save New Expense" action="{!save}" rerender="pb" >
<apex:param name="Exp_Date" value="{!Expense__c.Date__c}" assignTo="{!Exp_Date}"/>
<apex:param name="Exp_Type" value="{!Expense__c.Type__c}" assignTo="{!Exp_Type}"/>
<apex:param name="Exp_Amount" value="{!Expense__c.Amount__c}" assignTo="{!Exp_Amount}"/>
<apex:param name="Exp_Comments" value="{!Expense__c.Comments__c}" assignTo="{!Exp_Comments}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
<apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Controller code

```
public with sharing class ExpenseController
{

private ApexPages.StandardSetController sc;
private ApexPages.StandardController sc1;
public Integer SumOfAllExpenses {get; set;}
public Boolean isTwenty {get; set;}
public String pwd{get;set;}
public Boolean isNewExpense {get;set;}

public Date Exp_Date{get;set;}
public String Exp_Type{get;set;}
public Integer Exp_Amount{get;set;}
public String Exp_Comments{get;set;}


public ExpenseController(ApexPages.StandardSetController sc)
{
this.sc = sc;
SumOfAllExpenses = displayTotal();
isTwenty = getTwenty();
 
}


public Integer displayTotal()
{

List<AggregateResult> i = [SELECT SUM(Amount__c) FROM Expense__c];
SumOfAllExpenses = Integer.valueOf(i[0].get('expr0'));
return SumOfAllExpenses;
}

public void Custom_Delete()
{
System.debug('Checking for Pwd..');
List<Expense__c> l = [SELECT Id FROM Expense__c WHERE IsDeletedFromUI__c = true];
System.debug('Records to be deleted :'+l);
if(l.size() > 0)
{
if(pwd == 'KVN')
{
System.debug('Custom_Delete Invoked');

delete l;

System.debug('Custom_Delete Completed');
}
if(pwd != 'KVN' || pwd=='')
{
for(Expense__c ll : [SELECT Id FROM Expense__c WHERE IsDeletedFromUI__c = true])
{
ll.isDeletedFromUI__c = false;
update ll;
}


ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Incorrect Password.Delete Cannot Be Processed');
ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
}
}
}

public Boolean getTwenty()
{

Integer cnt = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Expense__c];
System.debug('Cnt variable is :'+cnt);
//Integer Cnt = Integer.valueOf(j[0].get('expr0'));
if(cnt > 20) 
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}


public PageReference save()
{
System.debug('Before Save - Comments Value :'+(Expense__c)sc.getRecord());
cancelNew();
System.debug('OUTSIDE INSERT'+Exp_Date+' '+Exp_Amount);   //*****LINE 0******

if(Exp_Date != null && Exp_Amount != null)
{
System.debug('WITHIN INSERT');
Expense__c e1 = new Expense__c();
e1.Date__c = Exp_Date;
e1.Amount__c = Exp_Amount;
e1.Type__c = Exp_Type;
e1.Comments__c = Exp_Comments;
insert e1;
}
sc.save();
Custom_Delete();
System.debug('After Save - Comments Value :'+(Expense__c)sc.getRecord());
displayTotal();
System.debug('After Total - Comments Value :'+(Expense__c)sc.getRecord());
PageReference p = new PageReference('/apex/addExpenses');
return p;

}

public PageReference cancel()
{
cancelNew();
sc.cancel();
displayTotal();
PageReference p = new PageReference('/apex/addExpenses');
return p;

}

public void needNew()
{
isNewExpense = true;
}

public void cancelNew()
{
isNewExpense = false;
}



}


}
```

My understanding so far :

a) User presses "Save" upon which save() in the controller extension class will be called.

b) I am also sending `<apex:param>`s to the corresponding properties in the controller.

c) I expect that at LINE 0, apex parameters from VF page (Exp_Date and Exp_Amount) will be sent but I am getting only null values as shown by the debug log.

```
06:36:07.106 (106966000)|USER_DEBUG|[85]|DEBUG|OUTSIDE INSERTnull 0
```

Can anyone let me know as to why my apex parameters are not sent to the controller properties ?

**UPDATE :**

Looks like there is an issue with

```
<apex:param name="Exp_Date" value="{!Expense__c.Date__c}" assignTo="{!Exp_Date}"/>
<apex:param name="Exp_Type" value="{!Expense__c.Type__c}" assignTo="{!Exp_Type}"/>
<apex:param name="Exp_Amount" value="{!Expense__c.Amount__c}" assignTo="{!Exp_Amount}"/>
<apex:param name="Exp_Comments" value="{!Expense__c.Comments__c}" assignTo="{!Exp_Comments}"/>
```

Because when I hard code  values like "xyz" instead of "{!Expense__c.Comments__c}" in the apex:param tag I can obtain "xyz" from the controller (as revealed from the log).

Is there anything wrong in the apex:param tag especially with "value" attribute assignment ?
Can someone let me know ?

Comment: Try removing ReRender and see if works ?

Comment: Also your Pagereference should return null   
return null;

Comment: I tried both i.e setting PageReference to NULL and removing rerender..still the same issue. In my log I am getting the following            07:41:33.064 (64273000)|USER_DEBUG|[85]|DEBUG|OUTSIDE INSERTnull null

Comment: @Mohith : Please see my update. I believe something wrong with my apex:param tag's value attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Apex:param tags can be tricky.They generally work great when you use rerender else sometime they fail. And most important they are able to pass string values to the the controller.

Can you try to convert the value of params to text before passing it ?

Something like

```
<apex:param name="Exp_Date" value="{!TEXT(Expense__c.Date__c)}" assignTo="{!Exp_Date}"/>
```

OR

```
<apex:param name="Exp_Date" value="{!JSINHTMLENCODE(Expense__c.Date__c)}" assignTo="{!Exp_Date}"/>
```

You can try with JSENCODE, I think for me the TEXT() function worked.

Comment: JSINHTMLENCODE worked for me. My issue was that the value was being retrieved from a Map, and somehow it was not getting converted to a string. This is what finally worked <apex:param assignTo="{!tobeRemoved}" value="{!JSINHTMLENCODE(eco.ecoDetailAccountMap[unique.id])}" name="tobeRemoved" />

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have checked that `Expense__c.Date__c` etc are not null for the object you are testing with?

The standard controller should automatically query any fields referenced in the page but it is also possible to nominate extra fields to be queried via [addFields](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm). The problem is probably elsewhere, but the explicit nomination is worth a quick try:

```
public ExpenseController(ApexPages.StandardSetController sc)
{
    this.sc = sc;
    sc.addFields(new String[] {
            String.valueOf(Expense__c.Date__c),
            String.valueOf(Expense__c.Type__c),
            String.valueOf(Expense__c.Amount__c),
            String.valueOf(Expense__c.Comments__c)
            });
    SumOfAllExpenses = displayTotal();
    isTwenty = getTwenty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need  to pass that data with Parameters.  The object in your controller should have them already.  You should save it in your controller though.

```
private Expense__c expense;

public ExpenseController(ApexPages.StandardSetController sc)
{
  this.sc = sc;
  SumOfAllExpenses = displayTotal();
  isTwenty = getTwenty();
  expense = (Expese__c) sc.getRecord();
}
```